# Reading a full line of text from .txt with white space into a single variable C++

Tags: c++, string, io

I'm having some trouble reading from a file.

My file contains multiple lines that all need to be saved into variables of different types. I was able to get the bools and the ints to transfer properly but I am having trouble with my strings, specifically strings that contain white space.

My file contains:

```
1
0  
1  
0  
0  
0
1
0
0
0
Chester Von Tester
1
1
```

I was able to get each line to properly read into individual variables but it freaks out when it gets to Chester Von Tester, either only inputting the first word or nothing at all depending on which method I use.

Here is the tidbit of code thats not working right (the entirety of code is a few hundred lines, don't think it is necessary to post):

```
loadGame >> newGame;
cout << typeid(newGame).name() << " " << newGame << endl;

loadGame >> bossOne;
cout << typeid(bossOne).name() << " " << bossOne << endl;

loadGame >> bossTwo;
cout << typeid(bossTwo).name() << " " << bossTwo << endl;

loadGame >> bossThree;
cout << typeid(bossThree).name() << " " << bossThree << endl;

loadGame >> bossFour;
cout << typeid(bossFour).name() << " " << bossFour << endl;

loadGame >> bossFive;
cout << typeid(bossFive).name() << " " << bossFive << endl;

loadGame >> bossDeathCount;
cout << typeid(bossDeathCount).name() << " " << bossDeathCount << endl;

//Position Coordinates

loadGame >> coord_x;
cout << typeid(coord_x).name() << " " << coord_x << endl;

loadGame >> coord_y;
cout << typeid(coord_y).name() << " " << coord_y << endl;

loadGame >> inCombat;
cout << typeid(inCombat).name() << " " << inCombat << endl;

//Character traits
getline(loadGame,characterName);
cout << typeid(characterName).name() << " " << characterName << endl;

loadGame >> characterGender;
cout << typeid(characterGender).name() << " " << characterGender << endl;

loadGame >> characterClass;
cout << typeid(characterClass).name() << " " << characterClass << endl;
```

Here is what happens when the code runs:

```
b 1
b 0
b 1
b 0
b 0
b 0
i 1
i 0
i 0
b 0
Ss 
i 0
i 1
```

It is getting all the type id's correct, which is a start. Where it's messing up is the name where it says "Ss" then a blank when it should say "Ss Chester Von Tester" followed by "i 1" not "i 0".

What would be the best way to get the entire line "Chester Von Tester" into that string variable?

Comment: You have to code those rules into your input parsing.  Is it always 3 strings that makes up the name?  If not, how are you going to know where the name ends?

Comment: Example: `1 0 0 0 "Chester Von Tester" 100 50 50` -- This is how many programs determine what makes up the entire string if it contains spaces, and that is to double quote the string.  Then you have to write the code to parse the double quotes correctly.

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated it. Theres no spaces in between, its a whole new line. The posting changed it for some reason. Also, the name can be any size with any number of spaces. There's no way to tell.

Comment: There's a `std::getline` function — that would probably help, followed by parsing of your `string` to convert numeric strings into numbers, and allow you to leave the text as text.

Comment: Please post the code on how you're reading this now.  If you're using `operator >>` to read in the string, it is going to stop at the first space.  You should be using `std::getline`.

Answer (score 3):

With out posting the code, it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do. You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function which will read one line per a function call.

Comment: You should also mention the issue that arises with mixing std::getline with std::cin. getline does not remove the newline character from the stream, so if cin is used after a getline, it will read an empty string

Comment: Just posted the code